# Why does $\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_1^\infty \Bbb F_2)$ have connected components that are not open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

To be honest, I don't even know how to describe all prime ideals in $\prod_1^\infty \Bbb F_2$. I know we get one for each $n \in \Bbb N$ corresponding to the set of elements that are zero in the $n$-th coordinate, and at least an extra one corresponding to the ultrafilter $F := \{x|x_i\ne 0 \,\text{for at most finitely many }i\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you write down is a filter, not an ultrafilter.

The ideals in a product of fields correspond to the filters on the index set. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter, the corresponding ideal is $\{a : \{i : a_i = 0 \} \in \mathcal{F}\}$. It follows that the prime ideals (which equal the maximal ideals in that case) correspond to the ultrafilters. The spectrum identifies with the Stone-Čech compactification of the index set.

So your question is really a topological one: Why does $\beta \mathbb{N}$ have a connected component which is not open? Well, it is totally disconnected and not discrete. So take any $p \in \beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, then $\{p\}$ is a connected component which is not open.

Comment: Dear Martin, take any subset of the index set. It either contains finitely many elements (in which case it is in my filter), or its complement contains finitely many elements (in which case the complement is in the filter). Hence my filter cannot be enlarged and is thus an ultrafilter. Where did I reason wrongly?

Comment: Your filter consists of those cofinite sets. The set of prime numbers is not finite and not cofinite.